# Generate unique email in c# for Microsoft Identity Manager

Tags: c#, email, identity

I have a DB ad Microsoft Identity Manager to generate user accounts from HR to MS Active Directory and so on.

I have a such code for generate unique email:

```
case "mailgenerate":
                if (mventry["email"].IsPresent) 
                {
                    // Do nothing, the mail was already generated.
                }

                 {

                    if (csentry["FIRST"].IsPresent && csentry["LAST"].IsPresent);
                   {
                        string FirstName = replaceRUEN(csentry["FIRST"].Value);
                        string LastName = replaceRUEN(csentry["LAST"].Value);
                        string email = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@test.domain.com";
                         string newmail = GetCheckedMail(email, mventry);

                          if (newmail.Equals(""))
                        {
                            throw new TerminateRunException("A unique mail could not be found");
                        }
                          mventry["email"].Value = newmail;
                        }
                }
                break;


   //Generate mail Name method
    string GetCheckedMail(string email, MVEntry mventry)
    {
        MVEntry[] findResultList = null;
        string checkedmailName = email;
        for (int nameSuffix = 1; nameSuffix < 100; nameSuffix++)
        {
            //added ; and if corrected
            findResultList = Utils.FindMVEntries("email", checkedmailName,1);

            if (findResultList.Length == 0)
            {
                // The current mailName is not in use.
                return (checkedmailName);
            }
            MVEntry mvEntryFound = findResultList[0];
            if (mvEntryFound.Equals(mventry))
            {
                return (checkedmailName);
            }
            // If the passed email is already in use, then add an integer value
            // then verify if the new value exists. Repeat until a unique email is checked
            checkedmailName = checkedmailName + nameSuffix.ToString();
        }
        // Return an empty string if no unique mailnickName could be created.
        return "";
    }
```

**Problem:**
When I run sync cycle for first time I get normal email like
duplicateuser1@test.domain.com
For next sync cycle this emails are updated to 
duplicateuser@test.domain.com1

This code I'm also using to generate mailnickname and accountname without any problems.

Can anybody say why it is happens?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
checkedmailName = checkedmailName + nameSuffix.ToString();
```

`checkedmailName` has a value like this: `firstName.lastName@test.domain.com`

So, you're doing this:

```
checkedmailName = firstName.lastName@test.domain.com + 1;
```

You need to do something like this:

```
checkedmailName = checkedmailName.Split('@')[0] + nameSuffix.ToString()+ "@" + checkedmailName.Split('@')[1];
```

Whith this, you're getting the part before `@`, adding a `int` value and then, appending the `@`+ `domain`.

---

**Updated by author of thread** I changed split -> Split and it works. Thanks!